# What does the _json function do and what library is it from?

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, passport.js, mean-stack

I've been looking a bit at the mean stack from https://github.com/linnovate/mean

I'm wondering what the _json method does in

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
        clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.findOne({
            'facebook.id': profile.id
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                user = new User({
                    name: profile.displayName,
                    email: profile.emails[0].value,
                    username: profile.username,
                    provider: 'facebook',
                    facebook: profile._json
                });
                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    return done(err, user);
                });
            } else {
                return done(err, user);
            }
        });
    }
));
```

Also it looks like an underscore function but I can't find anything in the underscore reference. Also does anyone know which library this is from?

Comment: It looks more like a property on the profile object that's passed into the anonymous function, rather than a function. The author perhaps meant to indicate (most likely to him/herself) that it's to be considered a private property.

Comment: Thanks I found it now, it's in the profile object that's passed back, it contains _raw and _json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a field that stores the raw JSON.  It is generated by the [Facebook module for Passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/blob/dcfc85d099206477235f9da389562f600df8c48f/lib/strategy.js#L162-L165):

```
var profile = parse(json);
profile.provider = 'facebook';
profile._raw = body;
profile._json = json;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `_name` is a common convention properties of objects that are for internal purposes, but completely legal for any case. With Underscore.js, you'll only be using `_.methodName`, not `_name`, so if you see the underscore object calling a method, it could likely be Underscore. Underscore uses `_name` for internal purposes, but you'd likely never using them.